# Abstraction in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have the following questions:

I'm developing an application that has the following entities:
"Person", "Individual", "Company", "Customer", "Supplier"

A "Person" entity is an abstraction. An "Individual" is a "person", but a "company" is also a "person" but with a few distinct attributes.

My question is: A "Client" may be one a "Individuals" but can also be a "company", how to store it in the database?

## [Option 1]

```
tbl_individual
id
person_id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N

tbl_company
id
person_id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N

tbl_customer
id
individual_id // Only completed when the client is "Individuals"
company_id // Only completed when the client is "Enterprise"
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N
```

## [Option 2]

```
tbl_person // Here placed the data of "Individuals" and "Company"
id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N

tbl_customer
id
person_id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N
```

Comment: The amount of information you've provided to ensure a good data model seems quite lacking, but I'll throw in my two cents.

Comment: The tables you're creating sound like you work for a start-up company that is creating some of its core database. You need to do a quality job before you build a bunch of applications over these tables.

tbl_company - shouldn't contain person_id. Create a separate company to person_id or individual_id association table to support a many person to at least one company relationship, although consider if a person can be related to many companies, you may want to support a many to many relationship there.

Can a company be a supplier and a customer? Can a person be in a company and a supplier?

Comment: No. A customer can be a company or a person, however can not be both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 seems fine. Just add column `type` for `tbl_person` and extra table `tbl_company_data`:

```
tbl_person // Here placed the data of "Individuals" and "Company"
id
type [1 - individual, 2 - company]
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N

tbl_customer
id
person_id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N

tbl_company_data
id
person_id
Data_1
Data_2
...
data_N
```